# How to enter data in textarea using mechanize or request in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to automate using python for generating PFAM domain image for protein sequence using https://pfam.xfam.org/generate_graphic. I tried to submit text in the textarea that is provided in the webpage. The following is the following code that i have tried. Any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests

url = 'https://pfam.xfam.org/generate_graphic'
params = {
    'text': '''{
  "length" : "534",
  "regions" : [
    {
      "type" : "pfama",
      "text" : "Peptidase_S8",
      "colour" : "#2dcfff",
      "display": "true",
      "startStyle" : "curved",
      "endStyle" : "curved",
      "start" : "159",
      "end" : "361",
      "aliEnd" : "350",
      "aliStart" : "163"
    },
    {
      "type" : "pfama",
      "text" : "PA",
      "colour" : "#ff5353",
      "display" : true,
      "startStyle" : "jagged",
      "endStyle" : "curved",
      "start" : "388",
      "end" : "469",
      "aliEnd" : "469",
      "aliStart" : "396"
    }
  ]
}'''  # this is the contents of the text area

}

# start a web-scraping session (mostly, for maintaining cookies)
session = requests.Session()
session.get(url)
print (session.get(url))
# submit the "form"
response = session.post(url, data=params)

data = response.json()
```

Best,
sameer

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you receive an error message? What do you try to do?

Comment: Yes. I get an error as JSONDecodeError: Expecting value..

Comment: When I try to add your `params` variable in a JSON file in VS Code I get an error because of your `'text': '''{...}'''`. Do you know your JSON format is correct?

Comment: I just copied the format provided as an example in https://pfam.xfam.org/generate_graphic

Comment: Of what type is `params`? You can check with `params.GetType()`

Comment: params is a dictionary. I do not see a GetType() function.